# How to make one container push another down in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want `container-2` to be fully visible but the boxes in `box2` cover it in mobile view. I don't want the size to be any different for the boxes in `box2` I just want `container 2` to be pushed down so it can be fully visible in mobile.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(152, 152, 152);
}
.container-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(46, 6, 6);
}
.box-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box1 {
  background-color: rgb(65, 186, 186);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: rgb(92, 191, 124);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .box1 {
    background-color: rgb(65, 186, 186);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .box2 {
    background-color: rgb(92, 191, 124);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="box-container">
      <div class="box1">

      </div>
      <div class="box2" id="box">
        <div class="box1" style="background-color: blue; height: 50%;"></div>
        <div class="box1" style="background-color: green;  height: 50%;"></div>
        <div class="box1" style="background-color: yellow;  height: 50%;"></div>
        <div class="box1" style="background-color: orange; height: 50%;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've tested your code , it is unclear to me the problem you are having. Seems to me that is working fine, but still it is currently 3AM so it might not help me.

Comment: The boxes inside box2 cover container 2 in mobile view.

Comment: I've tested in mobile view and I can perfectly see the `container-2` background-color

Comment: Yes but it is half way covered by the the boxes in box2.

Comment: I want container 2 to be fully visible but the boxes in box2 cover it.  I don't want the size to be any different for the boxes in box2 i just want container 2 to be pushed down so it can be fully visible in mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because you have inline CSS setting `height:50%` to `.box1` inside `#box`, which vertically (in mobile view) would sum up to `200%` therefore covering the `.container-2`, so set in mobile view to `25%`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(152, 152, 152);
}
.container-2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(46, 6, 6);
}
.box-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box1 {
  background-color: rgb(65, 186, 186);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
.box2 {
  background-color: rgb(92, 191, 124);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#box .box1 {
  height: 50%
}
#box .box1:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: blue
}
#box .box1:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) {
  background: red
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #box .box1 {
    height: 25%
  }
  .box1 {
    background-color: rgb(65, 186, 186);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .box2 {
    background-color: rgb(92, 191, 124);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box1">

    </div>
    <div class="box2" id="box">
      <div class="box1"></div>
      <div class="box1"></div>
      <div class="box1"></div>
      <div class="box1"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-2">
</div>
```

Comment: I want the boxes in box2 to collapse down beneath box1 in mobile view the way they do already.  I just want to make it so container2 will still be 100% visible an beanth the boxes in box2.

Comment: I just did in my snippet didn't I?  container(with box1+box2) then container2, My snippet does that.

Comment: Yeah you did sorry, i tried testing the code here on stack overflow and it didn't work right so i put it in the actual documents and it worked thank you!!

Comment: Now how would I make those boxes bigger in the box2 in mobile but not cover container-2?  I mean if you want to answer that.